# Wikidata Toolkit: Is it possible to access properties of entities?

Tags: java, mediawiki, wikidata, wikidata-api

First of all, I want to clarify that my experience working with wikidata is very limited, so feel free to correct if any of my terminology is wrong.

I've been playing with wikidata toolkit, more specifically their wdtk-wikibaseapi. This allows you to get entity information and their different properties as such:

```
WikibaseDataFetcher wbdf = WikibaseDataFetcher.getWikidataDataFetcher();
EntityDocument q42 = wbdf.getEntityDocument("Q42");
List<StatementGroup> groups = ((ItemDocument) q42).getStatementGroups();

for(StatementGroup g : groups) {
  List<Statement> statements = g.getStatements();
  for(Statement s : statements) {
    System.out.println(s.getMainSnak().getPropertyId().getId());
    System.out.println(s.getValue());
  }
}
```

The above would get me the entity Douglas Adams and all the properties under his site: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q42

Now wikidata toolkit has the ability to load and process dump files, meaning you can download a dump to your local and process it using their *DumpProcessingController* class under the wdtk-dumpfiles library. I'm just not sure what is meant by processing.

1. Can anyone explain me what does processing mean in this context?
2. Can you do something similar to what was done using wdtk-wikibaseapi in the example above but using a local dump file and wdtk-dumpfiles i.e. get an entity and it's respective properties? I don't want to get the info from online source, only from the dump (offline).

If this is not possible using wikidata-toolkit, could you point me to somewhere that can get me started on getting entities and their properties from a dump file for wikidata please? I am using Java.